# Is this the right way i should be coding my game to reset the score once the player dies?

Tags: c#

Score does not reach 0 once the player dies.

I tried all different kinds of methods and changing values but nothing seemed to work.

```
{
    //when the player's box collider collides with another box collider
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //scene moves to a game over screen
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Player Death");
            //Reset score everytime player dies
            void resetScore()
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", 0);
            }
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

It was just building the score up from where it left off and didnt do as i programmed.

Comment: I would be calling PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", 0); directly after the LoadScene().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset the score right when the player dies? I assume you reset it on game start. Try doing it right after the player dies, or use it in a constructor when creating a new game/player. It isn´t clear how you implemented it, it would help if you post more pieces of code.

[EDIT] 
Firstly, you are declaring the ResetScore Method, but you don´t call it to execute. So you need to declare it outside the "OnTriggerEnter" method, and then call it inside the method like this :

```
ResetScore();
```

Secondly, Why don´t you try to use property instead of SetInt?

```
public int Score { get; set;}
```

Then you can change it like this :

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Player.Score = 0;
        //scene moves to a game over screen
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Player Death");
        //Reset score everytime player dies
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new method `resetScore()` when a player dies, but you're never calling it.

What you should do is declare the method outside of `OnTriggerEvent()` and call it when a player dies:

```
//when the player's box collider collides with another box collider
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //scene moves to a game over screen
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Player Death");
        //Reset score everytime player dies
        resetScore();
    }
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{ }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void resetScore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
}
```